# Different guiding_lines_colos for different leaf nodes in ETE3 using TreeStyle class or anything else

Tags: python, etetoolkit, ete3

How how can I add different colors for guiding line (connecting leaf node with the text using [guiding_lines_color in TreeStyle class](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/reference/reference_treeview.html)) in ETE3 python module.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use TreeStyle.guiding_lines_color

http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/reference/reference_treeview.html#ete3.TreeStyle

Comment: Hi @jhc. I need different guide lines color for leaves.

Comment: then I don't think you can get it easily. If the branch lengths of the tips can be faked in your tree, there would be a trick though: i) convert tree into ultrametric: e.g. https://www.biostars.org/p/172568/#172820 ii) modify node.img_style['hz_line_color'] for each tip node.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @jhc. Unfortunately none of them resolve my problem.